# VueJS prevent tabbing to variable elements when var is true

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a pretty simple collapsible-div accordion component, which works.

This can take any sort of content via the `slot` feature.

There is a toggle data property (`collapsed`) used to control a class on the wrapper and do the collapsing.

The content may include things like form elements, which for usability we would not want to allow to be tabbed to when hidden (`collapsed===true`), but allow to be tabbed to when not hidden (`collapsed===false`).

So far I've tried putting `tabindex=""` (and `-1`) on the content wrapper, which does not work. I've also tried putting `disabled="disabled"` on the content wrapper, which messes with my events on the inner elements but does not prevent tabbing to them.

I can probably manually iterate through all elements in the content block in vanilla javascript when the toggle happens, but that seems anti-pattern to VueJS.

Anyone know how I can blanket disable tabbing onto any element inside a given element without such an iteration? Preferably within VueJS, but some CSS or data property I'm unaware of would be acceptable.

Comment: use a higher tab index? like 3000

Comment: @DerekPollard unfortunately no, that just makes the content wrapper tab-able, albeit last, but the contents retain their default tabbing order.

Comment: Yikes. The problem with the -1 is that _chrome_ doesn't support it since the W3C spec states its range from 0 to 3XXX

Comment: @DerekPollard hence the use of `tabindex=""` to prevent tabbing to an element that's normally tab-able  (-1 'works' because it breaks the browser, but is technically the wrong way to do so)

Comment: have you tried just using `v-show` on the whole form? I assume you're passing props to the slot

Comment: @DerekPollard the slot is any kind of HTML, and it is necessarily present as it is animated in/out and not conditionally rendered.

Comment: Vue would still apply transition effects to v-show elements

Comment: and v-show is still present, just hidden

Comment: @DerekPollard v-show toggled display:none css property, which again breaks the sliding transition animation we have. We need the content to be there and "visible"